# Получить ответ на запрос в google в виде текста

Tags: google-chrome, htmlagilitypack

Здравствуйте, как можно получить html со всеми ссылками и содержанием (то есть текстом на странице) на запрос вида: "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=". Использую HtmlAgilityPack.
Так не получается:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(wc.OpenRead(linkforgoogle));
string s = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```